# MacBook Pro El-Capitan erase / format CD-RW

Tags: macos, disk-format

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro running OSX El Capitan 10.11.6. I cannot erase a CD-RW that I have inserted into it. Disk Utility's erase button is disabled for it, and Finder's menu for the mounted CD does not show 'Erase rewritable disc'.

System Information reports that it supports CD-RW and it knows the media in the drive is a CD-RW.

Pictures supporting this are here: [screenshots from my Mac](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3vzHZmGDdwKbUFiLXNCTWZ4WEU&usp=sharing):

[image: Finder sidebar]

[image: Disc Burning info]

[image: System info]

How the heck do I format this CD??

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question: I couldn't find a way to do it in the GUI but used the command line:

```
drutil bulkerase quick
```

I would welcome a way to do this via the GUI though.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've already found a way, but I thought I'd suggest a method that might possibly help that has a GUI.

From my experience, El Capitan's Disk Utility has been basically useless, and I've had several times like you describe where it just flat out refuses to let you do things. I would highly recommend getting the old, less useless Yosemite Disk Utility back following the instructions [here](http://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/restore-yosemite-disk-utility-on-el-capitan.180578/), as this solved all my issues recently:

**Option 1 - From a Backup**
1. Copy `Disk Utility.app` from the `/Applications/Utilities` folder of a Yosemite Time Machine backup to somewhere convenient (like your desktop)
2. Download a hex editor (I personally like [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/))
3. Right click your copied Yosemite Disk Utility and click "Show Package Contents."
4. Go to `Contents/MacOS` within the package contents and open the file called "Disk Utility" with your hex editor
5. Find the chunk `D584C00F 85440100` within the file (near or on line 25056 in Hex Fiend) and change the '85' in the second half to '84'.
6. Save the file. You should now be able to run this copied Disk Utility.
Note: you may have to give root:wheel ownership:
`sudo chown -R 0:0 ~/Desktop/Disk\ Utility.app`

**Option 2 -  From a Download**
1. Copy your El Capitan Disk Utility somewhere else besides `/Applications/Utilities`
2. Run [this script](https://gist.github.com/geoff-codes/b96bc9c5bca538aa0819), which downloads the Yosemite Recovery Update, copies out Disk Utility, and patches the version for use on El Capitan.
Note: It also tries to copy it over the current El Capitan Disk Utility, which failed on my machine due to system permissions. But this is why I added step 1.

Answer (score 0):

To do in GUI, it is possible in Finder.

1. Insert Disk
2. Open with Finder
3. Right click the disk object.
4. Erase should be in the drop down.

Comment: Sadly, as you can see from the screenshots the "erase" option is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what to do then...I think that @Testing 's answer may be the one you are looking for.